# Python.BeautifulSoup: Trying to scrape for plain text on a website within a given style using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

https://my.sa.ucsb.edu/public/curriculum/coursesearch.aspx

Hit search right away and it will lead you to a list of courses, times, and etc.

When I input other style elements I get something but not with the current style.

I'm looking to scrape the time data for each course and I'm using `beautiful soup` and my calls are

```
courseTimes = soup.find_all("td", {'style':'text-align: left;
vertical-align: top;'})

print courseTimes
```

But it returns `[]` which is nothing.

edit: Hey sorry I wasn't clear before. It's not my website so I'm using beautiful soup to parse the HTML data. The website contains plain text wrapped in

`<td style = "text-align: left; vertical-align top;" >9:00AM - 10:30AM</td>`

Here is my full code:

```
def parse_course_listings_for_lectures(self, raw_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
    courseT = soup.find_all("td", {'style':'text-align: left; vertical-align: top;'})
    print courseT
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will scrape the time for each of the rows you are seeking, one of the problems is that you are required to click the search button to get your data. This can be accomplished with URLIB request module or Selenium. BS is just a tool to scrape with, here is a solution in python 3.X, you will need to get the correct [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) for what browser you decide to use :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://my.sa.ucsb.edu/public/curriculum/coursesearch.aspx')

availbutton = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_pageContent_searchButton')
availbutton.click()

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
rowindex = 0
while rowindex < 36:
        i = 0
        table_row=soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'CourseInfoRow'})[rowindex]
        for td in table_row:
                if (i == 15):
                        print(td)
                i = i + 1
        rowindex = rowindex + 1
```

Sample Output:

```
<td class="Header Clickable" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; padding-left: 5px;
                            padding-right: 5px;">
                            2:00pm - 3:20pm
                        </td>
```

Comment: Hi, when i try to run this code it says that oddrowindex is not defined. could this be a mistake or am i missing something? it also only prints for me one time repeated over and over again.

Comment: also why is rowindex < 36? is ti because on that particular course site there are 36 CourseInfoRow's?

Comment: how would i make it work across the different classes? it seems that < 36 only works if there are 36 CourseInfoRow's

Comment: nvm figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: Edited code to correct oddrowindex should be rowindex